# Python to PHP valuables

Tags: php, python, mysql, variables

I'm new to the whole python thing. Wanting to learn, I created a small script that passes two values from python into PHP, using the `$_GET['']` method, then PHP writes them to a MySQL DB. I was thinking about just using python to talk to the MySQL DB, but that means I can't have my MySQL server be IP White-listed anymore. Because what if I use this script at another location that's not registered.

anywho, Here is my php script:

```
$v1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['v1']);
$v2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['v2']);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `values` (ID, value1, value2) VALUES ('', '$v1', '$v2')") or die(mysql_error());
```

I have the values in python (`value1 = "test1", value2 = "test2"`). But my question is, how do I go about sending them to the web server and is `$_GET['']` the best way of going about this? I figure, if I'm going to learn, why not learn the right way, right? All I need help with is, passing the variables to PHP and saving them to `$value`. once I have them in `$value` I can take it from there.

Comment: you definitively should read up about REST, messaging systems and similar topics.

Comment: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html

Comment: also, SQL injection. And the big red box in the PHP documentation for `mysql_*`.

Comment: Yes, I understand about SQL injections. I just started with the python yesterday. I haven't had the time to fill in the blanks.

Comment: The injection vulnerability is in your PHP code, not Python. You should *never* write code like that, even for a throwaway practice script.

Comment: Yes, I still understand. 
I have include mysql_real_escape_string(). As of right now I just want to get the concept of getting the two languages talking together. I have already included it in my code.

Comment: Escaping strings suggests you don't understand. Just use [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and let them worry about the hard business of making parameters safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically, you want to make a `GET` request from Python.

By far the nicest way to accomplish that is by using the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library. More or less straight from the [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls):

```
>>> import requests
>>> payload = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
>>> r = requests.get("http://httpbin.org/get", params=payload)
```

Note that this is a third party library you have to install, e.g. with `pip`. If that is not possible for some reason, you can also use [`urllib`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html) and [`urllib2`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html).

```
from urllib import urlencode
import urllib2

payload = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
params = urlencode(payload)
r = urllib2.urlopen('http://httpbin.org/get?' + params)
```

Note that this example assumes Python 2.x

Comment: Worked perfectly... after installing requests. Thanks for the help.